# Paid app on computer (via google play store) but installed on phone as 'unknown sources' (not via the play store)

Tags: google-play-store

I just paid for 2 apps on my computer logging into the play store.
But I installed them on my phone as .APKs so how to have the **free** versions turn into **paid**?

Comment: you're telling that you have purchased two apps from play store. Then why don't you install it officially from play store?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this myself.
I downloaded the respective PRO versions. I guess these versions have access to the "play store receipts" and so both apps booted the Pro versions properly.

Comment: Perfect, good to hear ! Don't forget to remove the old unused .APK apps to avoid conflicts ;)